# How to set python virtualenv and start the flask project from shell script.

Tags: python, bash, shell, flask, virtualenv

I have two python flask projects. To start these projects I manually source virvualenv and then start app.py

```
#From project 1 directory 
source venv/bin/activate 
python app.py 


#From project 2 directory
source venv/bin/activate 
python app.py
```

Now I want to start these projects from one shell script after sourcing them to their corresponding virtualenv. 
How to do that. I tried googling and executed some shell commands but did not work out.

Comment: if you are using windows you should try activating them in multiple cmds, are those `source` statements working ?

Comment: did you use auto active virtualenv? https://gist.github.com/codysoyland/2198913

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678993/automatically-load-a-virtualenv-when-running-a-script

Answer (score 1):

You can run by using the full path of the python for the corresponding project.

**< project_path >/venv/bin/python < project_path >/run.py**

Comment: Project1/venv/bin/python  Project1/run.py
Project2/venv/bin/python  Project2/run.py   second line in shell script is not executing as my first program is still running.

Comment: Put ";" between 2 commands like: Project1/venv/bin/python Project1/run.py; Project2/venv/bin/python Project2/run.py, also make sure both the projects are running on separate ports.

Comment: Hi thanks. yes it is running in separate ports. I figured out a way to execute both the command from script without waiting for other jobs to finish by adding & symbol at the end of each command.