# When launching a Python script using shell_exec, the script doesn't work

Tags: php, python-3.x, virtualenv, rembg

I have written a Python script that removes the background of an image using the `rembg` library and then composes the image using PIL.

For this project, a `virtualenv` was created and `rembg` was installed there.
All of this is on an Ubuntu 20.04 server.

The project folder is located at `/var/www/work/py/banner_generator` and contains a virtual environment folder called venv. The Python script itself is located at `/var/www/work/py/banner_generator/banner_generator.py`. If I run the command `/var/www/work/py/banner_generator/venv/bin/python3.8 /var/www/work/py/banner_generator/banner_generator.py` from the console, it works as intended.

However, I need to run this script in a PHP script. When I execute the code in PHP:

```php
$cmd = "/var/www/work/py/banner_generator/venv/bin/python3.8 /var/www/work/py/banner_generator/banner_generator.py";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);

echo $output;
```

Nothing happens. When I commented out the code and left only "print("work")" in the Python script, everything worked from PHP.

I decided to comment out my code and test it. First, in the Python script, I left only "print("work")" and checked it. In this case, everything worked from PHP. Then I decided to continue experimenting and uncommented all my imports, resulting in the following code:

```python
import argparse
import os
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter, ImageEnhance
import requests
from io import BytesIO

print("work")
```

I ran it again and it didn't work. The "work" statement didn't show up.

Then I started commenting out some imports and, through trial and error, discovered that the problem only occurred when importing rembg. In other words, the following code works:

```python
import argparse
import os
# from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter, ImageEnhance
import requests
from io import BytesIO

print("work")
```

Interesting fact: PIL is only installed in the virtual environment, yet its import does not cause any problems. However, for some reason, importing rembg causes issues.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23762093/740553 didn't work?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans unfortunately, it didn't help. But when I run the PHP file from the console as a root user, everything works. However, when I run it from the browser (as www-data), it doesn't work. Could this be related to the fact that rembg saves its models in the /root/.u2net folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include the path to the rembg library in your PHP script before running the Python script. For example:

```php
putenv("PYTHONPATH=/var/www/work/py/banner_generator/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages");
$cmd = "/var/www/work/py/banner_generator/venv/bin/python3.8/var/www/work/py/banner_generator/banner_generator.py";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $output;
```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help. But when I run the PHP file from the console as a root user, everything works. However, when I run it from the browser (as www-data), it doesn't work. Could this be related to the fact that rembg saves its models in the /root/.u2net folder?