# Should I install `pre-commit` into a python virtual environment or python global environment?

Tags: pre-commit.com

I'm developing python code on a Windows machine. When I have a new python package I am working on I create a virtual environment named `.venv` with `python -m venv .venv`. I activate the venv using `.venv\Scripts\activate`. When working on the package I install package dependencies such as `numpy` with `(.venv) C:\...\my_package> pip install numpy`.

I am trying to figure out how I should install the `pre-commit` package so that I can use pre commit hooks during version control of the package source code and related materials.

One workflow (following the philosophy of **never** installing anything in the base python install) would be to

1. Activate the virtual environment
2. install `pre-commit` into the virtual environment
3. write the `.pre-commmit-config.yaml` file
4. run `pre-commit install` in the package/repo directory
5. Run `git` commands, ensuring the virtual environment is activated (otherwise `pre-commit` will not be able to run properly)

The major downside to this strategy is that it REQUIRES the virtual environment to be activated for git commands to work. This is a bit strange since normally you don't need python for git to work, and you might even be version controlling a repository that is not even python code!

The alternative workflow would be

1. install `pre-commit` into the global python installation. Now `pre-commit` is available as a command line command anywhere on the system.
2. write the `.pre-commmit-config.yaml` file
3. run `pre-commit install` in the package/repo directory
4. Run `git` commands, `pre-commit` should always work.

The downside here is you're messing with your global python installation and you may run into weirdness if e.g. you have multiple python installations on your system.
A similar strategy might be to use a tool like `pipx` to do a "global" installation of `pre-commit`.

What is a recommended installation strategy for `pre-commit`?

Comment: On UNIX systems, a program can have a shebang that specifies a virtualenv and thus use that virtualenv without it being activated. I'd be very surprised if this weren't also possible on Windows. (See [Automatically load a virtualenv when running a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678993) giving a general / not-Windows-specific overview).

Answer (score 1):

One nice solution to this problem is to use [pipx](https://pipx.pypa.io/stable/). `pipx` essentially provides a middle ground between installing nothing to the global python installation and installing everything to the global python installation. `pipx` is installed into the global python installation and then you use `pipx` to (1) install (and manage) python-based command line tools (such as `pre-commit`) within isolated virtual environments and (2) expose those command line tools to the global terminal command namespace. The workflow in this case is:

1. `python -m pip install --user pipx` to install `pipx` to the global python.
2. `pipx ensurepath` to make sure path is setup correctly.
3. `pipx install pre-commit`
4. `pre-commit install` in the git repo of interest
5. set up `.pre-commit-config.yaml` in the git repo of interest
6. Now `git` commands should work using `pre-commit` (which uses the `pre-commit` installed by `pipx`) on the repo of interest, whether or not the virtual environment is activated.